# How to update a Value in a ConcurrentHashMap threadsafe

Tags: java, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I need to update a value in a ConcurrentHashmap but I am not sure on how to do this thread safe.

The Hashmap is a ConcurrentHashMap and I need to get the instance of the custom class, perform some operations on it and then put the updated value back in.

Is there any way to combine this get-alter-put operation to something atomic?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use ConcurrentHashMaps computeIfPresent https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-

But since computeIfPresent is a costly operation as its atomic and some update operations will be blocked by other threads during the computation of the BiFunction . You can preclude this with a read operation on concurrent hashmap which is pretty fast and if that returns not null , invoke computeIfPrsent

Below code gets the value of key "1" and adds 100  to it and puts in back to the map in a atomic way

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        map.put(1,100);
        Integer value = map.get(1);
        if (value != null)
            map.computeIfPresent(1, (key, oldValue) -> oldValue + 100);
    }
```

Comment: In OP's case keys are supposed to exist in Map, so value check doesn't make sense. `#computeIfPresent` is almost always non-blocking if you work with different keys (considering good hash function).

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesnt the seperatoin of  map.get and computeifpresent break the atomicness? Couldnt there be changes to the value in map in the meantime?

Comment: Apparently no , because the atomic read-modify-write operation is still achieved by computeIfPresent.

Comment: but null check happens before the update in computeIfPresent. let's say the value is null? maybe you check my answer or correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Surely this is not correct, in fact, if another thread update the map after the get (let's say with -1) and before the computeIfPresent you will insert 200 instead of 99.

Answer (score 2):

A [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)'s `computeIfPresent` method is a possibility. From the javadocs: If the value for the specified key is present, attempts to compute a new mapping given the key and its current mapped value.  The entire method invocation is performed atomically (*expects that computation should be short and simple*).

How does the method work, in general? Some example code:

Consider a `Map<String, Integer>` `map` with keys and values: `{four=4, one=1, ten=10, two=2, three=3, five=5, eleven=11}`

(1) updates the mapping with new value (note the lambda is a [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) returning a newly computed value):

`map.computeIfPresent("ten", (k, v) -> new Integer(100));`

(2) the function returns a null, the existing mapping is removed:

`map.computeIfPresent("eleven", (k, v) -> null);`

(3) the mapping is not added, as there is no existing mapping:

`map.computeIfPresent("twenty", (k, v) -> new Integer(20));`

**EDIT:**

Note on `compute()`: Using the same input `map` data (and method arguments), the `compute` method works similarly but for the case 3. Note the case 3 where new mappings can be added:

(3) a *new* mapping is added.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can use

```
map.compute(key,  (k,v) -> {
                      if(k != null) {
                        return v+1;
                      } else {
                        return some_var;
                      }
                    });
```