# ConcurrentHashMap[String, AtomicInteger] or ConcurrentHashMap[String, Int] for thread-safe counters?

Tags: scala, concurrency, thread-safety, counter, scala-collections

When incrementing concurrent counters by key in `ConcurrentHashMap` is it safe to use regular `Int` for value or do we have to use `AtomicInteger`? For example consider the following two implementations

**`ConcurrentHashMap[String, Int]`**

```
final class ExpensiveMetrics(implicit system: ActorSystem, ec: ExecutionContext) {
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  private val chm = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Int]().asScala

  system.scheduler.schedule(5.seconds, 60.seconds)(publishAllMetrics())

  def countRequest(key: String): Unit =
    chm.get(key) match {
      case Some(value) => chm.update(key, value + 1)
      case None => chm.update(key, 1)
    }

  private def resetCount(key: String) = chm.replace(key, 0)

  private def publishAllMetrics(): Unit =
    chm foreach { case (key, value) =>
      // publishMetric(key, value.doubleValue())
      resetCount(key)
    }
}
```

**`ConcurrentHashMap[String, AtomicInteger]`**

```
final class ExpensiveMetrics(implicit system: ActorSystem, ec: ExecutionContext) {
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  private val chm = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, AtomicInteger]().asScala

  system.scheduler.schedule(5.seconds, 60.seconds)(publishAllMetrics())

  def countRequest(key: String): Unit =
    chm.getOrElseUpdate(key, new AtomicInteger(1)).incrementAndGet()
  
  private def resetCount(key: String): Unit =
    chm.getOrElseUpdate(key, new AtomicInteger(0)).set(0)

  private def publishAllMetrics(): Unit =
    chm foreach { case (key, value) =>
      // publishMetric(key, value.doubleValue())
      resetCount(key)
    }
}
```

Is the former implementation safe? If not, at what point in the snippet can race-condition be introduced and why?

---

<sup>The context of the question are AWS CloudWatch metrics which can get very expensive on high-frequency APIs if posted on each request. So I am trying to "batch" them up and publish them periodically.</sup>

Comment: Relevant: [How to update a value in a ConcurrentHashMap threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376675/how-to-update-a-value-in-a-concurrenthashmap-threadsafe). Talks about combining get and set into an atomic operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first implementation is not correct, because the `countRequest` method is not atomic. Consider this sequence of events:

- Threads A and B both call `countRequest` with key `"foo"`
- Thread A obtains the counter value, let's call it x
- Thread B obtains the counter value. It's the same value x, because Thread A hasn't updated the counter yet.
- Thread B updates the map with the new counter value, x+1
- Thread A updates the map, and because it obtained the counter value before B wrote the new counter value, it also writes x+1.

The counter should be x+2, but it is x+1. It's a classic lost update problem.

<del>The second implementation has a similar problem due to the use of the `getOrElseUpdate` method. `ConcurrentHashMap` does not have that method, therefore the Scala wrapper needs to emulate it. I think the implementation is the one inherited from `scala.collection.mutable.MapOps`, and it is defined like so:
```
  def getOrElseUpdate(key: K, op: => V): V =
    get(key) match {
      case Some(v) => v
      case None => val d = op; this(key) = d; d
    }
```
This is obviously not atomic.</del>

To implement this correctly, use the [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method on `ConcurrentHashMap`.

This method will execute atomically, so you won't need an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: I think implementation of [concurrent.Map#getOrElseUpdate](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/cd8410d30427747bbcd1c94429ce1509e527a315/src/library/scala/collection/concurrent/Map.scala#L94) uses `putIfAbsent` which documentation states is [atomic](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html#concurrent-maps).

Comment: You're correct. `JConcurrentMapWrapper` does extend `MapOps` as I said and inherits a non-atomic `getOrElseUpdate` implementation from there. But it *also* inherits from `scala.collection.concurrent.Map`, which overrides that implementation with an implementation that is in fact atomic.
Nevertheless I think that `compute` is still better, because with an `AtomicInteger` you need to synchronize twice, once on the map and once on the `AtomicInteger`.