# Best practice to update ConcurrentHashMap with atomic values

Tags: kotlin, collections, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have the `ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicReference<String>>` map and I need to update some value in there.
I wrote the following code:

```
map.compute(key) { _, value ->
   value?.also { reference -> 
      reference.set(getNewValue())
   }
}
```

It works well, but I'm not sure that it is an optimal solution for this case. Is there any kind of better practice?

Comment: `compute` does already perform the computation under a lock, so there’s no point in using an additional `AtomicReference<String>`. You can simply use a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376675/how-to-update-a-value-in-a-concurrenthashmap-threadsafe

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is not clear with your current code:

```
map.compute(key) { _, value ->
   value?.also { reference -> 
      reference.set(getNewValue())
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is indeed your intent, but, with what you wrote, if the key doesn't exist, it will not insert the new value. The lambda will receive `null` for `value`, and your lambda definition will return the same `null`.

To show your intent more clearly, make it more obvious:

```
map[key]?.also { reference -> 
  reference.set(getNewValue())
}
```

But as Holger says in the comment to your question, there's no point using an AtomicReference. Use `ConcurrentMap<String, String>` instead:

```
map.computeIfPresent(key) { getNewValue() }
```

However:

**If your intent is actually to update existing *or* insert new value**

then just do this:

```
map[key] = getNewValue()
```

If, for some strange reason, you really *must* use an `AtomicReference`, then do this:

```
map.getOrPut(key, AtomicReference<String>()).set(getNewValue())
```